# Setting up gradle and project structure for Kotlin Multiplatform project

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I want to build a CLI tool with Kotlin Multiplatform which runs on Linux, Macos and Windows.

But I am struggling with setting up my `build.gradle` and my project structure. I am using `IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1` and created my basic project with `File -> New -> Project -> Kotlin / Native | Gradle`

Currently I am looking through guides from [kotlinlang.org](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html) but I am more falling then achieving something.

So far my `build.gradle` looks as follows:

```
plugins {
   id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform' version '1.3.72'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
kotlin {
// For ARM, should be changed to iosArm32 or iosArm64
// For Linux, should be changed to e.g. linuxX64
// For MacOS, should be changed to e.g. macosX64
// For Windows, should be changed to e.g. mingwX64

     linuxX64("linux") {

     }
     mingwX64("mingw") {

     }
     macosX64("macos") {
         binaries {
             executable {
            // Change to specify fully qualified name of your application's entry point:
                entryPoint = 'sample.main'
            // Specify command-line arguments, if necessary:
            runTask?.args('')
        }
    }
}

sourceSets {
    commonMain {
        kotlin.srcDir('src/main')
        resources.srcDir('src/res')
        dependencies {
            implementation kotlin('stdlib-common')
            implementation "com.github.ajalt:clikt-multiplatform:2.7.0"
        }
    }
    commonTest {
        dependencies {
            implementation kotlin('test-common')
            implementation kotlin('test-annotations-common')
        }
    }

    macosX64().compilations.test.defaultSourceSet {
        dependsOn commonMain
    }
    // Note: To enable common source sets please comment out           
    'kotlin.import.noCommonSourceSets' property
    // in gradle.properties file and re-import your project in IDE.
    macosMain {
    }
    macosTest {
    }
}
}

 wrapper {
    gradleVersion = "6.4.1"
    distributionType = "ALL"
}
```

And my project structure is still basic:

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DW3UG.png)

Formerly I only worked on Android Projects with Kotlin, and I guess I am spoiled with gradle as Android generates the most basic stuff and everything is working without doing that much.

I understand that I need to create packages like `linuxMain` and `mingwMain`, but where to I put common sourcesets? I tried to create a package called `commonMain`, but it won't even let me create Kotlin files in that package.

When I am finished I want to have (in the best case) one common source set and one entry point for all my targets. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you specify your commonMain source set's source locations as `/src/main/`. By default, it's usually set onto `/src/commonMain/kotlin/`. So if you will remove those `srcDir` settings and create a .kt file in your `/src/commonMain/kotlin/` folder, everything should work fine. Also, I hope you have removed 'kotlin.import.noCommonSourceSets' property from your `gradle.properties` as your script recommended.